# Android: Crop video while recording using MediaCodec and MediaMuxer

Tags: android, graphics, glsurfaceview, video-recording, grafika

I am trying to record the video using GLSurfaceView and audio from the AudioRecord. In MediaMuxer I am sending both audio and video data when onFrameAvailable called. I set the camera preview size of 1280 * 720 and preview on the full screen. 
I am having problem to crop the frame to 600 * 600. Can anybody help me to crop the video frame before encoding to MediaCodec and MediaMuxer.

I am taking help from the Grafika android demo code

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve to problems:

1. Record video with 600 * 600: Use video codec with specified width,
   height. This is easy to do, but it could be that not all phones have
   hardware codecs that will supports you custom resolution.
2. Scale video in the way it will look not stretched because you have changed w/h ratio. Use view matrix passed to OpenGL shader with
   needed scale.

Comment: Can you please elloborate the second point. Give an example for the "Use view matrix passed to OpenGL shader "

Comment: @AmitThaper Were you able to achieve this?